# Howto check if a powershell command succeeded or not?

Tags: exchange, powershell, powershell-v3.0, exchange-2016, powershell-v4.0

Is it possible to check if a powershell command succeeded or not?

Example:

> Set-CASMailbox -Identity:blocks.5 -OWAMailboxPolicy "DoNotExists"

caused the error:

```
Outlook Web App mailbox policy "DoNotExists" wasn't found. Make sure you typed the policy name correctly.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Set-CASMailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 9C5D12D1,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetCASMailbox
```

I think that it should be possible to fetch the FullyQualifiedErrorId so I tried the following:

> $test = Set-CASMailbox -Identity:blocks.5 -OWAMailboxPolicy "DoNotExists"

But it looks like the error isn´t transferred into the test variable.

So what is the correct way here to perform something like:

```
$test = Set-CASMailbox -Identity:blocks.5 -OWAMailboxPolicy "DoNotExists"
if ($test -eq "error")
{
Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command failed"
}
else
{
Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command completed correctly"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [`Set-CASMailbox` reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125264(v=exchg.160).aspx):

- `OwaMailboxPolicy` parameter:

> The `OwaMailboxPolicy` parameter specifies the Outlook on the web
> mailbox policy for the mailbox. You can use any value that uniquely
> identifies the Outlook on the web mailbox policy. For example:
>
> - Name
> - Distinguished name (DN)
> - GUID
>
> The name of the default Outlook on the web mailbox policy is Default.

- [Cmdlet Input and Output Types](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkId=616387). *If the Output Type field is blank, the cmdlet doesn’t return data* (it's the `Set-CASMailbox` case).

Read [about_CommonParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) (*the parameters that can be used with any cmdlet*), apply either `ErrorVariable` or `ErrorAction`:

**`ErrorVariable`**:

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity:blocks.5 -OWAMailboxPolicy "DoNotExists" -ErrorVariable test
if ($test.Count -neq 0)      ### $test.GetType() is always ArrayList
{
    Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command failed: $test"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command completed correctly"
}
```

**`ErrorAction` and *Try,Catch,Finally*** (read [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) *how to use the Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to handle **terminating** errors*):

```
try {
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity:blocks.5 -OWAMailboxPolicy "DoNotExists"  -ErrorAction Stop
                ### set action preference to force terminating error:  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑
    Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command completed correctly"
}  
catch {
    Write-Host "The Set-CASMailbox command failed: $($error[0])"  -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

In any case, read **[Write-Host Considered Harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JosefZ's answer the automatic variable `$Error` contains an array of errors, so you could look at $Error.Count property to see if it went up. I think `-ErrorVariable` though is the best answer. see `Get-Help about_AutomaticVariables` for details.